# How to redirect to custom urls?

Tags: node.js

I'm setting up an admin panel, and the admin enters his custom url in a textarea that stores in the db by clicking `enter`. Now I want to redirect him to the custom url that he entered already. How is that possible?
In the below code how can I declare the `customURL`from database?

```
router.get('/blog/'+customURL, (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err
    var dbo = db.db("barg")
    var query = { username: "a" }
    dbo.collection("post").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log(result[0].url)

      res.render('blog',{
        post : result[0].content
      })
      db.close()
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to use is a path parameter, and check if the path provided is a valid URL. If it's not, you end the request with: `404 - Not found`

```
router.get('/blog/:path', async(req, res) => {

  // check if req.params.path is a valid URL in DB
  const validUrl = await isValidUrl(req.params.path);
  if(!validUrl) {
    return res.status(404).send('not found');
  }

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err
    var dbo = db.db("barg")
    var query = { username: "a" }
    dbo.collection("post").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log(result[0].url)

      res.render('blog',{
        post : result[0].content
      })
      db.close()
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Should I use valid-url library or something like that?

Comment: No, isValidUrl is your function to check whether that url is valid for you blog, whether it exists on the database or something, it's not a package.